# What happened to the hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash, stackexchange

Is it true that hats disappear every January 1st? Or did they disappear for good?

Forgive my ignorance but I am a relatively new member.

Comment: As per the [voting thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11706/8348), Winter Bash 2013 ended on 3 Jan 2014, at which point the hat went "back into storage".  I would not be surprised to see a Winter Bash 2014, with an all-new collection of hats for users to earn and wear (meaning the 2013 styles are gone).

Comment: I would love to see see those hat boxes in user profiles.